# Generic Types & the toArrayMethod

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

I have a class `MyStack<T>` which defines the following

```
public T[] toArray(){
  int s=size();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  T[] result=(T[])new Object[s];
  Node n=first;
  for (int i=0; i<s; i++){
     result[i]=n.data;
     n=n.next;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Since this returns an array of type `T`, I would think that if I declared this instance: `MyStack<String> s=new MyStack<>`, that the following would be perfectly valid: `String[] test=s.toArray()`. I think this because since `s` is of type `String`, `toArray` should return an array of type `String`, since `String` has basically been substituted in for every `T` in this class (only for this particular instantiation, I know). The only way this runs without errors is if I do this: `Object[] test=s.toArray()`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, hold on a minute. Suppose your hypothesis were correct that `String` were substituted for every `T`.

Would the following cast be valid?

```
String[] result = (String[])new Object[s];
```

No, it would not. We can be sure that a `new Object[]` is not a `String[]`.

Now sometimes you will see something like `(T[])new Object[n]` but it only works because the cast actually becomes [erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) inside the generic class. (It is a deceptive idiom.)

When the class gets compiled, what actually happens is that references to `T` are replaced with its upper bound (probably `Object` unless you had something like `<T extends ...>`):

```
public Object[] toArray(){
  int s=size();
  Object[] result=new Object[s];
  Node n=first;
  for (int i=0; i<s; i++){
     result[i]=n.data;
     n=n.next;
  }
  return result;
}
```

And the cast is moved to the call site:

```
MyStack stack = new MyStack();
String[] arr = (String[])stack.toArray();
```

So in fact, while the cast is erased inside the class, the cast does happen once the value is returned to outside the class, where `ClassCastException` is thrown.

The inability to instantiate arrays (and objects in general) generically is why the Collections framework defines their [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-) method to take the return array as an argument. A simple version of this for you would be like the following:

```
public T[] toArray(T[] inArray){
    int s = size();

    Node n = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        inArray[i] = n.data;
        n = n.next;
    }

    return inArray;
}
```

For some ideas on how to create an array generically, you may see [*'How to create a generic array in Java?'*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java); however you will need the caller to pass some argument to the method.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, type erasure. Taken from the Java website:

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

What this means is that, when your code is compiled, `MyStack<String>` is compiled into `MyStack<Object>`. This is to make sure that generics do not incur an overhead by needing to create new classes. How does this apply to you? Well..

```
MyStack<String> s = new MyStack<>();
```

is converted into..

```
MyStack<Object> s = new MyStack<>();
```

Now, this means that when you call the `toArray` method, the only type that can be *guarenteed* is the `Object` type. The compiler can't be sure that everything it returns is of type `String`, so it won't let you treat it as a `String`, due to the strong typing in Java. So, what is the only variable type left?

```
Object[] array = s.toArray();
```

**Extra Reading**

- [Type Erasure in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: 'Because erasure' does not actually answer the question here. It only explains why the exception is thrown from a weird spot.

Comment: I guess I'm slightly confused then. If the best we can do is say that `s` is a stack filled with `Objects`, which all other classes descend from, why even bother with the generic types? What am I missing here?

Comment: @user50210 The problem is that you are trying to cast `Object[]` in to a `String[]` and it's not a valid cast.